# Inventory balance report that aggregates Issue and Receive transactions by warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4bWf.png)

I'm creating an inventory balance report that aggregates Issue and Receive transactions by warehouse
I was able to do this, but finally I need to get the total of the inputs and outputs over the warehouses. How do I do this?
As seen in the picture, there are 4 inputs to the 'AA001TX' warehouse, 2 are outputs, and the last value should be 2 warehouse stock. How can I get the total?

```
SELECT MOL.ITEM_CODE,
CASE WHEN MOL.TO_LOCN_ID IS NOT NULL 
THEN MOL.TO_LOCN_ID
ELSE
MOL.FROM_LOCN_ID
END AS 'ANBAR'
,CASE WHEN MOL.TO_LOCN_NAME IS NOT NULL
THEN MOL.TO_LOCN_NAME
ELSE 
MOL.FROM_LOCN_NAME
END 'Anbar Adı',
(CASE WHEN MOL.TO_LOCN_ID IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(DEMAND_QTY) 
ELSE 
-SUM(DEMAND_QTY)
END) AS SUMTOT

FROM AZP_MOL MOL WHERE ITEM_CODE  ='1010000003'  
GROUP BY MOL.ITEM_CODE,MOL.TO_LOCN_ID,MOL.TO_LOCN_NAME,MOL.FROM_LOCN_ID,MOL.FROM_LOCN_NAME   ORDER BY ANBAR ASC
```

I tried to get the total stock value but I failed.

Comment: please do not post image. Edit your question and include your sample data, query and expected result as text

Comment: Also, please [edit] the title into a short description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that query.

```
SELECT RESULT.ITEM_CODE,RESULT.ANBAR,RESULT.[Anbar Adı],SUM(RESULT.SUMTOT) AS 
'SUMTOT' FROM 
(SELECT MOL.ITEM_CODE AS 'ITEM_CODE',
CASE WHEN MOL.TO_LOCN_ID IS NOT NULL 
THEN MOL.TO_LOCN_ID
ELSE
MOL.FROM_LOCN_ID
END AS 'ANBAR'
,CASE WHEN MOL.TO_LOCN_NAME IS NOT NULL
THEN MOL.TO_LOCN_NAME
ELSE 
MOL.FROM_LOCN_NAME
END 'Anbar Adı',
(CASE WHEN MOL.TO_LOCN_ID IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(DEMAND_QTY) 
ELSE 
-SUM(DEMAND_QTY)
END) AS 'SUMTOT'

FROM AZP_MOL MOL WHERE ITEM_CODE  ='1010000003'  
GROUP BY             
MOL.ITEM_CODE,MOL.TO_LOCN_ID,MOL.TO_LOCN_NAME,MOL.FROM_LOCN_ID,
MOL.FROM_LOCN_NAME) AS RESULT
GROUP BY RESULT.ANBAR,RESULT.[Anbar Adı],RESULT.ITEM_CODE
ORDER BY RESULT.ANBAR ASC
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Comment: please explain the answer